# Bind 'this' identifier to the function of an element

Tags: jquery, this

I am having trouble using the identifier `This` in a html element when using jquery.

**Expected result:**

Whenever I get to select a Language option from Dropdown, it has to validate. I also select a level from the dropdown.

To accomplish this, I need to transform '.LanguageBlock' into a **This** selector.

**Attempt:**

My attempt was to use Children() and Parents() and I am sure it would work but I am having problems with the This selector.

I think I also have to use the **.each** combined with the **This** selector

HTML

```
<div class="LanguageBlock">
    <select class="Language">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value="1">English</option>
    </select>
    <select class="Level">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value="1">Basic</option>
    </select> <br></br>
</div>
<div class="LanguageBlock">
    <select class="Language">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value="1">English</option>
    </select>
    <select class="Level">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value="1">Basic</option>
    </select>
</div>
 <br></br>
    <a id="submit" style="border-radius:50%;border:1px solid red;padding:10px">Submit</a>
```

Javascript

```
var Validator = 1;
$('#submit').bind('click', function(){
  var Language =  $('.LanguageBlock').children('.Language').val();    
  var Level = $('.LanguageBlock').children('.Level').val();  

    if(Language!='' && Level==''){
        Validator = 0;
    }

    if (Validator==0){
        alert('Must select a level for the current language you selected');
        return false;
    }

});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t99mU/7/)

Comment: It doesn't really look like the submit button has any children, nor does it have matching parents, so all your assumptions are wrong.

Comment: thanks for repplying @adeneo I edited my question. what I need to use as a 'This' selector is .LanguageBlock I think I can do that using an each function

Comment: Why are you defining such variables? In the eyes of a JavaScript programmer they hold references to Classes.

Comment: so That I can do a validation for each of the '.LanguageBlock' elements @undefined and yes exactly, they must hold a reference to a class! you know, the Class Language and Class Level must be related (for their validation). I can relate them using a parent (.LanguageBlock)

Comment: I didn't mean `className`/`class` attribute. I meant JavaScript Classes. Of course, you are free to define identifiers! Also `this` is a keyword not a selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about like this:

```
$('#submit').bind('click', function(){
  $('.LanguageBlock').each(function() {
     var Language =  $(this).find('.Language option:selected').val();    
     var Level = $(this).find('.Level option:selected').val();

    if(Language!='Select' && Level=='Select'){
        Validator = 0;
    }

    if (Validator==0){
        alert('Must select a level for the current language you selected');
        return false;
    }

   });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t99mU/10/

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! @BryanElliott that's pretty much what I needed. I just made a few adjustments and the code works pretty pretty fine.